# How can https:// sites be accessed from an iPod Touch behind a proxy server that requires authentication?

Tags: iphone, proxy, ipod-touch

On my iPod Touch 4th generation (latest generation as of the original time of this posting), when I'm at work, I can successfully access the Internet by connecting to my office's wi-fi network.  The network requires a set of basic authentication credentials to access the Internet.  When I open the browser on the iPod Touch and attempt to access an http:// site, I am prompted for my credentials; after successfully entering my credentials, I am able to continue and access the site.

However, I cannot access any https:// sites.  If I attempt to access https://owasp.org/, for example, I never get prompted for credentials; instead, the browser just does nothing -- the spinning "loading..." indicator up at the top of the screen appears, but otherwise nothing happens.  (I can get to this same site fine from my laptop PC connected to the same wi-fi network.)

The problem appears to be that the iPod Touch software only supports proxy servers that require basic authentication over http, but not https.

Is there any solution or workaround allowing an iPod Touch to access https sites through a proxy server that requires authentication?

Comment: Once you have authenticated against the proxy once in your session, do you have to enter your credentials again for each different website you visit?

Comment: @music2myear Once I have authenticated against the proxy for one http website, I no longer need to enter my credentials for any http websites.  (This seems to last for about a day or so.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you authenticate while accessing a http site and then enter a url for an https site?

As in, does the proxy remember your credentials for subsequent sites visited in a single session?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give this a try on Monday.

Comment: I just tried the following at work from my iPod: (1) Visited http://google.com/ (http) - I got prompted for credentials and then was able to access the site. (2) Visited https://owasp.org/ (https) - Got prompted for credentials and then *was* able to access the site(!). (3) Vistied https://www.fidelity.com/ (https) - Did *not* get prompted for credentials, was *not* able to access the site (per the original problem reported above).  I *am* able to access https://www.fidelity.com/ (https) from my laptop PC on the same network.  So I'm confused as to the iPod's behavior at this point...

Comment: It sounds like different sorts of sites have different sorts of security settings. I don't really know all that much about proxy interaction with https. My answer was pretty much a guess based on my experience with proxies normally requiring only one login per session. Someone who knows more about browsing on the ipod may be able to answer whether new processes are spawned for each website visited.